Event for hiding worksheets based on cell value
I have a list of 365 days in a year on Sheet1 (LIST).
I created 365 worksheets that are numbered 1 - 365
On the main page (LIST) there is a drop down selection box with "View" or "Hide" as an option.
I am trying to create a private sub that will hide or show sheets with matching names based on the cell value "View"/"Hide"
EX: (LIST)
1 View
2 View
3 Hide
4 Hide
5 View
I would like only sheets named "1", "2", and "5" to be visible
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim sheetname As String
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set rng = Range("F2:F366")

    For Each cell In rng
    
        sheetname = Cells(cell.row, "A").Value
        ws = Worksheets("sheetname")        
     
        If cell.Value = "View" Then
            ws.Visible = True
        ElseIf cell.Value = "Hide" Then
            ws.Visible = False
        End If

    Next cell

End Sub

The code was running with errors after changing selections on the main page. Now, it doesn't seem to be running.
The worksheet_selectionChange code is attached to the LIST worksheet.

The Worksheet_SelectionChange event triggers when users select cell(s), which may not be ideal since no actual changes (desired sheet status) to the cells occur. The Worksheet_Change event would be more suitable for your situation.
Microsoft documentation:

Worksheet.SelectionChange event (Excel)


Worksheet.Change event (Excel)

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim sheetname As String
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    ' sheet status range
    Set rng = Me.Range("F2:F366")
    ' changed cell(s) in rng
    If Not Application.Intersect(rng, Target) Is Nothing Then
        ' loop through cell
        For Each cell In Application.Intersect(rng, Target).Cells
            ' Trim convert cell content to string and remove non-printable chars
            ' If cell content is a number (ie. 3), Sheets(3) might be different with Sheets("3")
            sheetname = Trim(Me.Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value)
            ' get sheet object
            set ws = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set ws = Worksheets(sheetname)
            On Error GoTo 0
            ' sheet exists
            If Not ws Is Nothing Then
                ' change visibility
                If cell.Value = "View" Then
                    ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible 
                ElseIf cell.Value = "Hide" Then
                    ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden 
                End If
            End If
        Next cell
    End If
End Sub



Run below script to initialize sheet status

Private Sub SheetStatus()    
    Dim sheetname As String
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    ' sheet status range
    Set rng = Sheets("List").Range("F2:F366")
    ' loop through cell
    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        sheetname = Trim(Sheets("List").Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value)
        ' get sheet object
        set ws = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = Worksheets(sheetname)
        On Error GoTo 0
        ' sheet exists
        If Not ws Is Nothing Then
            ' change visibility
            If cell.Value = "View" Then
                ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible 
            ElseIf cell.Value = "Hide" Then
                ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden 
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub


Awesome. Thanks for the massive cleanup of my code.
Just starting to debug.
ws = Worksheets(sheetname) is returning nothing.
Trying to figure that out now.

Please run SheetStatus() to initialize the sheet statuses. The Worksheet_Change event will handle any changes made by users afterward.

It's a typo. Try Set ws = Worksheets(sheetname), and  adding the Trim function in sheetname = Trim(...) to remove any non-printable characters from the cell.

Yeah, I found the set ws = mistake on my end.
Many thanks my friend.
Working like a charm!

A Worksheet Change: Hide Sheets Using a List of Drop-Down Lists

Your suspicions were correct; you were using the wrong event.
Remember, drop-down lists work perfectly with the Worksheet Change event.

A Quick Fix
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' prefix t - target - the sheet with the list
    ' prefix o - other - the sheets to be shown or hidden
    
    ' In a sheet module, the sheet is referenced using the 'Me' keyword.
    ' Its name is not used so the code stays flexible and can be used
    ' for a different worksheet without any changes.
    ' 'Target' represents all the cells that were manually changed at a point
    ' of time i.e. you could copy 'View' to several cells.
    ' Additionally, at the same time, you could have also copied cells outside
    ' the target column. Therefore you need to use 'Intersect' to exclude
    ' the latter, resulting in 'trg'.
    ' To initialize i.e. to adjust the visibility to the list,
    ' select the whole range and do a copy/paste i.e. 'Ctrl+C / Ctrl+V'.
    Dim trg As Range: Set trg = Intersect(Me.Range("F2:F366"), Target)
    If trg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no cells in the target range were changed
    
    Dim ows As Worksheet, tcell As Range, oSheetName As String
    ' Note that it is mandatory to declare 'oSheetName' as a String.
    ' Otherwise, the numbers would refer to the sheet indices.
    
    For Each tcell In trg.Cells ' looping through '.Cells'!
        ' When writing numbers to a String variable, VBA will automatically
        ' take care of the conversion but it is good practice
        ' to be explicit about it ('CStr').
        oSheetName = CStr(cell.EntireRow.Columns("A").Value) ' explicit 'CStr'
        ' Never use double-quotes for variables!
        ' Don't forget the 'Set' keyword when referencing an object (worksheet)!
        Set ows = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(oSheetName) ' specify the workbook
        If tcell.Value = "View" Then
            ows.Visible = xlSheetVisible ' use the correct argument
        ElseIf tcell.Value = "Hide" Then
            ows.Visible = xlSheetHidden ' use the correct argument
        'Else ' if neither (e.g. blank)?
        End If
    Next tcell

End Sub

